# How to populate collectionview from Json file?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms

I receive and deserialize the json file and now I need populte with same data ona collectionview in Xamarin Forms.
Here the json file:

```html
{
    "response": "OK",
    "Data": [
        {
            "N_PARTE": "POLEA PARA BULL",
            "DESCRIPCION": "POLEA PARA BULL C/BALERO Y ANILLOS",
            "INV_EXISTE": "0",
            "UNI_MEDIDA": "PZ"
        },
        {
            "N_PARTE": "polea para bull c/baleros y anillo ",
            "DESCRIPCION": "polea para bull c/balero y anillo ",
            "INV_EXISTE": "1",
            "UNI_MEDIDA": "PZ"
        },
        {
            "N_PARTE": "2170993",
            "DESCRIPCION": "ESTRACTOR DE POLEA O BALERO ",
            "INV_EXISTE": "0",
            "UNI_MEDIDA": "PZ"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need the follow format in the collectionview:

```html
-------------------------------------------------
PARTE:
DESC:
INV:
MEDIDA:
------------------------------------------------
```

Now I fill a ListView using the following code, but I need to change the list view to CollectionView and display the data as I mention.

```html
public ObservableCollection<string> itemlist;    
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            itemlist = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            listparts.ItemsSource = itemlist;
        }


var msjdes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<entrada>(responseText);
                string rspserver = msjdes.response;
                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    if(rspserver == "OK")
                    {
                        itemlist.Clear();
                        foreach (var item in msjdes.Data)
                        {
                            
                            itemlist.Add("PARTE:"+item.N_PARTE+"DESC:"+item.DESCRIPCION+"INV:"+item.INV_EXISTE+"MEDIDA"+item.UNI_MEDIDA);
                           
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
```

Comment: what **specifically** are you having problems with?  A `CollectionView` is very similar to a `ListView` and it is usually trivial to convert one.  Since you have not actually posted the XAML for your ListView it's difficult to give you specific advice.  It's also not clear why you don't use `msjdes.Data` as your ItemsSource, since that contains all of the data you need to display

Comment: you're right i just used msjdes.data in ItemsSource and work :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you provided, I wrote a minimal example for your reference.

Here is the xaml code:

```
<StackLayout>
    <CollectionView x:Name="myTest">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate >
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding N_PARTE}"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding DESCRIPCION}"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding INV_EXISTE}"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding UNI_MEDIDA}"></Label>
                </StackLayout> 
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is the cs code:

```
string json = "{\"response\": \"OK\",\"Data\": [{\"N_PARTE\": \"POLEA PARA BULL\",\"DESCRIPCION\":\"POLEA PARA BULL C/BALERO Y ANILLOS\",\"INV_EXISTE\": \"0\",\"UNI_MEDIDA\": \"PZ\"}, {\"N_PARTE\": \"polea para bull c/baleros y anillo \",\"DESCRIPCION\": \"polea para bull c/balero y anillo \",\"INV_EXISTE\": \"1\",\"UNI_MEDIDA\": \"PZ\"},]}";
public MainPage()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     Class1 res= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1>(json);
     myTest.ItemsSource = res.Data;
}
```

Here is the entity class code:

```
public class Class1
{    
    public string N_PARTE { get; set; }
    public string DESCRIPCION { get; set; }
    public string INV_EXISTE { get; set; }
    public string UNI_MEDIDA { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Class1> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]